# Fancy Media Queries with some LESS Magic

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, media-queries

It would be nice to wrap css-styles for different resolutions within some css-classes using less.

I'd like to do something like:

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
}

.tablet {
  footer {
    width: 768px;
  }
}

.desktop {
  footer {
    width: 940px;
  }
}
```

At the end something like this should be the result:

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  footer {
    width: 768px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  footer {
    width: 940px;
  }
}
```

.tablet could look somehow like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .tablet {

  }
}
```

Hope somebody has a nice idea!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media Query grouping instead of multiple scattered media queries that match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503862/media-query-grouping-instead-of-multiple-scattered-media-queries-that-match)

Comment: Based on the conversation in the comments to @zzzzBov, perhaps we need a bit more clarity in your question about _what_ you are trying to achieve and _how_ you are wanting to achieve it.

Answer (score 249, accepted):

Here is what I've done in my projects:

```
@desktop:   ~"only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px)";
@tablet:    ~"only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px)";

@media @desktop {
  footer {
    width: 940px;
  }
}

@media @tablet {
  footer {
    width: 768px;
  }
}
```

This allows you to only define your media queries once and you can use it throughout your less files.  Also a little easier to read. :)

Comment: This is awesome, thanks @Hai! A minor issue in Visual Studio is that this warning message is generated on the usage of `@media` in a .less file: "*Unexpected '@' block in the style rule*". It doesn't seem to be a problem though.

Comment: Why can't I pull the `@media` into the variables defined in line 1+2 ? ➪ regrettable a pure `@tablet { ...` doesn't resolve then, while a `@media @tablet {...` (resulting in a doubled `@media` of course, if taken into the string.

Answer (score 123):

I completely agree with Hai Nguyen's answer (which has been accepted) but you can clean it up a bit more by doing something like this:

```
@desktop:   ~"only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px)";
@tablet:    ~"only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px)";

footer{
  width: 100%;
  @media @tablet {
    width: 768px;
  }
  @media @desktop {
    width: 940px;
  }
}
```

It's essentially the same thing but lets you nest your media queries inside of the original selector. It keeps all css for a specific element together and makes your styles much more modular (vs the split breakpoint approach).

Comment: After reading this, I found this Grunt task to group the MQs after the nested MQs are compiled: https://github.com/buildingblocks/grunt-combine-media-queries

Removes the bloat.

Comment: This is nice and clean. Can I ask, why the ~ in front of "only...?

Comment: In LESS, a tilde ~ before a string "" literal outputs the string as-is, because it may be a syntax error in pure LESS.

Comment: what if you try to make an operation inside of that "literal string"? Let's say that I want to use a variable to contain the screen resolution, for instance: Can I do something like:  ~"only screen and (min-width: @mySize - 20px)". I know it does not work, but what's the correct way for doing that?

Answer (score 48):

+1 for Nguyen and Yancey - and one more addition.

If you want **explicit definition** of the widths, you can accomplish that with `string interpolation` and variables for your breakpoints. Here for example with those of bootstrap - the strict rules are to prevent definition overlapping.

```
@screen-xs-min:     480px;
@screen-sm-min:     768px;
@screen-md-min:     992px;
@screen-lg-min:     1200px;

@screen-xs-max:     (@screen-sm-min - 1);
@screen-sm-max:     (@screen-md-min - 1);
@screen-md-max:     (@screen-lg-min - 1);

@phone:             ~"only screen and (max-width: @{screen-xs-min})";
@phone-strict:      ~"only screen and (min-width: @{screen-xs-min}) and (max-width: @{screen-xs-max})";
@tablet:            ~"only screen and (min-width: @{screen-sm-min})";
@tablet-strict:     ~"only screen and (min-width: @{screen-sm-min}) and (max-width: @{screen-sm-max})";
@desktop:           ~"only screen and (min-width: @{screen-md-min})";
@desktop-strict:    ~"only screen and (min-width: @{screen-md-min}) and (max-width: @{screen-md-max})";
@large:             ~"only screen and (min-width: @{screen-lg-min})";

footer{
    width: 100%;
    @media @tablet {
        width: 768px;
    }
    @media @desktop {
        width: 940px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this "-strict" excactly about, from what you have written I am not capable of understanding the construct. Is there any source you could point me to for further reading on this topic?

Comment: Actually, the "strict-queries" are for convenience and should only be used, if you want your CSS to apply to a single screen range exclusively. When using mobile first (e.g. see: http://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/), I would say, that their usage is possibly a bit of a design smell and I would normally try to avoid them. But depending on the circumstances you might want some (heavy) CSS to target, say `@tablet` exclusively, and you do not want to override it in, say `@desktop` and/or `@large`. In these cases, you can use a strict query (here `@tablet-strict`).

Answer (score 11):

And you can also combine media queries like this

```
 @desktop:   ~"only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1199px)";
 @tablet:    ~"only screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 959px)";

    @media @desktop, @tablet, @ipad{ 
    
    //common styles... 
    
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

We use a setup like this:

```
@vp_desktop:    801px;
@vp_tablet:     800px;
@vp_mobile:     400px;

.OnDesktop(@rules) { @media screen and (min-width:@vp_desktop){ @rules(); } };
.OnTablet(@rules) { @media screen and (max-width:@vp_tablet){ @rules(); } };
.OnMobile(@rules) { @media screen and (max-width:@vp_mobile){ @rules(); } };
```

You only need to set variables, the mixins handle the rest so it's very easy to maintain yet still flexible:

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  .OnTablet({
    display: block;
  });
}
```

It is worth mentioning that while this technique is very easy, if used badly your CSS output will be full of media queries. I try to limit my media queries to 1 per-breakpoint, per-file. Where a file would be header.less or search.less.

N.B. This method probably won't compile unless you're using the javascript compiler.

Answer (score 4):

I am using these mixins & variables

```
.max(@max; @rules){@media only screen and (max-width: (@max - 1)){@rules();}}
.min(@min; @rules){@media only screen and (min-width: @min){@rules();}}
.bw(@min; @max; @rules){@media only screen and (min-width: @min) and (max-width: (@max - 1)){@rules();}}

@pad: 480px;
@tab: 800px;
@desktop: 992px;
@hd: 1200px;
```

So this

```
footer{
    width: 100%;
    .bw(@tab,@desktop,{
        width: 768px;
    });
    .min(@desktop,{
        width: 940px;
    });
}
```

becomes

```
footer {
  width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  footer {
    width: 768px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  footer {
    width: 940px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And this is what I have used for my project:

```
    @mobile:   ~"only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px)";
    @tablet:    ~"only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)";
    @ipad:    ~"only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1024px)";

    @media @mobile {
      .banner{
        width: auto;
      }
    }

    @media @tablet {
      .banner{
        width: 720px;
      }
    }

  @media @ipad {
      .banner{
        width: 920px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@highdensity:  ~"only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)",
               ~"only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)",
               ~"only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2)",
               ~"only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)";

@mobile:        ~"only screen and (max-width: 750px)";
@tab:       ~"only screen and (min-width: 751px) and (max-width: 900px)";
@regular:        ~"only screen and (min-width: 901px) and (max-width: 1280px)";
@extra-large:  ~"only screen and (min-width: 1281px)";
```