# String interpolation for LESS Variables

Tags: less, string-interpolation

I have a media query in LESS: `@media (max-width: 1079px) { ... }`. Basically I want to create a variable in LESS in which I can just say `@media (*LESS variable goes here*) { ... }` in my stylesheets. How can I interpolate the string `max-width: 1079px` into a LESS variable to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancy Media Queries with some LESS Magic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837808/fancy-media-queries-with-some-less-magic)

Answer (score 1):

For the variable, you could [escape the string value](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions):

```
@media-max-width: ~"max-width: 1079px";
```

Code snippet:

```
@media-max-width: ~"max-width: 1079px";

@media (@media-max-width) {
  p {
    color: #f00;
  }
}
```

Which will output the following:

```
@media (max-width: 1079px) {
  p {
    color: #f00;
  }
}
```

You could also include the parenthesis in the variable too:

```
@media-max-width: ~"(max-width: 1079px)";

@media @media-max-width {
  p {
    color: #f00;
  }
}
```