# Define Media queries in less

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to define my mobile support matrix in one place using `less`.
I also looked at examples from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837808/fancy-media-queries-with-some-less-magic) StackOverflow question.

**Approach 1: Not working**

```
@my-device-min-width: 375px;
@my-device-max-width: 414px;
@my-device-orientation: portrait;

@phoneRules: ~"only screen and (min-width: {@device-min-width}) and (max-width: {@device-max-width}) and (orientation: {@device-orientation})";
```

**Approach 2: Not working**

```
@my-device-min-width: {min-width: 375px;};
@my-device-max-width:  {max-width: 414px;};
@my-device-orientation: {orientation:portrait;};


@phoneRules: only screen and  (@device-min-width) and (@device-max-width) and (@device-orientation);
```

Please provide some explanation along with an answer to help me understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS?

```
@media screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width:767px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* Your code here */
}
```

(it'll work in Less too.)